# How can I set a CALayer delegate to use for Core Graphics drawing?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, delegates, core-graphics, calayer

I am trying to understand how I can use Core Graphics to draw on my CALayer. So far I think I know that I should set a controller object as the delegate of the layer, and then call my CG commands in the controller.

My problem is that I really cant figure out how to do this with my current code.

Ideally I need to have many different layers, all with different CG drawings on them, so I can animate them using CAAnimation. As of right now, I have a few working layers with animation, but no CG content on them. I have been trying to set all of these layers to the same delegate and then use an if statement to call each layer and draw to them. Is this even possible? Or I guess is there a simpler way to do this? I'm still rather new to these concepts so any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my relevant code:

in my TapView.h

```
@interface TapView : UIView
{
    CALayer *circleGlowLayer;

}
-(void)glowCircleTap;
@property (nonatomic) float opacity;
@end
```

In my TapView.m

```
@implementation TapView

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self glowCircleTap];
}
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

   if(self)
    {
        circleGlowLayer = [[CALayer alloc]init];
        [circleGlowLayer setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,470.0,470.0)];
        [circleGlowLayer setPosition:self.center];

        UIColor *transparent = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.53 green:0.85 blue:0.89 alpha:1.0];
        CGColorRef cgTransparent = [transparent CGColor];
        [circleGlowLayer setBackgroundColor:cgTransparent];

        [[self layer] addSublayer:circleGlowLayer];
        [circleGlowLayer setOpacity:0.0];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)glowCircleTap
{


    CAKeyframeAnimation *glowCircleFader = [CAKeyframeAnimation     animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    [glowCircleFader setValues:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], nil]];

    [glowCircleFader setDuration:0.5];
    [circleGlowLayer addAnimation:glowCircleFader forKey:@"fadeAnimation"];
}
@end
```

As of now this code draws a square when I tap the screen, and then fades it out over a half a second. I would like to be able to draw on this layer.

For my attempt at making a delegate, I have made a TapViewDelegate class and then in my -init in TapView I would `[circleGlowLayer setDelegate:TapViewDelegate];` And then this is where I get a bit lost. Additionally, if this is close, am I able to set all of my layers to this one delegate? I think the issue is that the idea of a delegate is still going over my head. Thanks in advance for any help!